# What is this little temple in the Outlands in the Planescape Campaign Setting?

Tags: dnd-5e, maps, planescape

I'm playing through the *Turn of Fortune's Wheel* campaign (from *Planescape: Adventures in the Multiverse*). One of my players saw this little temple floating on a giant leaf and wants to go there.  We're in Part 2 (the Outlands) so they could go see it.

[image: A section of the Outlands near The Spire, with a little temple drifting on a leaf circled in red]

What is this little temple in the Outlands?

I've tried to find info online but couldn't find anything.  If needed, I'll just come up with something myself but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm able to tell, that isn't any specific location? I'm not familiar with any references in Planescape lore, or broader D&D lore, to a temple floating in a lake on a leaf, nor can I find any myths that it might be referring to. I can't say with absolute certainty, but I believe that's just a bit of color for the map.

Out of curiosity, since it looks Japanese-inspired, I did do a quick bit of checking to see if any deities from Japanese myth canonically lived in the Outlands, but no luck on that front either. However, [Watatsumi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watatsumi) doesn't have a canonical location so far as I can tell, so there might be some inspiration to be had there for your players' trip. Further, that body of water is the Tir fo Thuinn from Celtic mythology, which might also give you some inspiration.

Comment: Hello
I pretty much figured there wouldn't be any lore since there was no text next to it.  Thanks for answering